# Asymptotics (Landau symbols)

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f(x)g(x)=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$ and also $f(x)=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Does this imply that $g(x)=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$?

I think this is a direct consequence of the properties of [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Since $f=O(1)$ and $f\cdot g=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$, we have that

$$O(1)=f\cdot g =O(g)$$
as $x\to\infty$.

But this should directly imply that $g=O(1)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for instance $g(x)=x$, $f(x)=\frac1x$.